# Send emails from subdomains on Devise not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to configure devise emails sent to be valid for a subdomain (by default all links point to main domain).

I'm following this:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Send-emails-from-subdomains

Problem is that I'm getting this error

```
NoMethodError in Devise/passwords#create

Showing     /Users/user/Sites/site/app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.haml where line #6 raised:

undefined method `subdomain' for #<User:0x007fb0019be868>
```

I'm calling `subdomain` from the view:

```
# app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html
%strong= link_to t('devise.confirmation_instructions.confirm_my_account'), confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token, :subdomain => @resource.subdomain)
```

Running Rails 3.2.3, devise 1.8.6

Comment: How are you calling `subdomain`? The error indicates you're calling it as an instance method on a `User` object, which would be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding the subdomain in the environment config.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "subdomain.domain.com" }
```